# Taking a value from a Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

My database developer created a Stored Procedure whom return the last ID, but not like output parameter.

```
.
.
.
        SET @NewContractSvcLID = @@IDENTITY
        RETURN @NewContractSvcLID
END
```

How I can get that value in PHP using MSSQL?
Thanks.

Note.
I was trying like a result set (mssql_fetch_row) but with a simple echo I saw a different result, just a "1".

Comment: Teach your db developer how to use output parameters

Comment: Will this do it for you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Comment: @steve is `SQL-SERVER` as you can see in the tag

Comment: @Steve, my question is about MS SQL. Anyway, I want get result from Stored Procedure. So, your comment don't help. I am sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought your question was about getting the MSSQL return value through your PHP code. Since your question said, "How I can get that value in PHP using MSSQL?"  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I find a solution. I don't know it's the best, but it works. 
When you are binding the parameters you have to bind the `RETVAL`(return value), then
when mssql_execute is called, the stored procedure executes and the values for the output parameters if they exist are returned as well as the RETVAL return value.

**Note:** Type => SQLINT4 assuming that the value is INT

Example:

```
$stmt = mssql_init($your_sp_name);
mssql_bind($stmt, "RETVAL",$return_value,  SQLINT4);

$result = mssql_execute($stmt);

echo $return_value;//output your return value
```

[The manual says:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php#refsect1-function.mssql-bind-parameters) `The PHP variable you'll bind the MSSQL parameter to. It is passed by reference, to retrieve OUTPUT and RETVAL values after the procedure execution.`

But when I pass by reference the variable a get error 500.

```
mssql_bind($stmt, "RETVAL",&$return_value,  SQLINT4);//get error 500
```

---

```
mssql_bind($stmt, "RETVAL",$return_value,  SQLINT4);//this will works
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write an ad-hoc query to return the value as a resultset.

```
DECLARE @return_value INT
EXEC @return_value = MyProcedure
SELECT @return_value
```

Comment: Yes, but I insist, I can't modify the database.

Comment: You don't need to modify the database, just run that whole batch as your query parameter.  Something like `mssql_query("DECLARE return_value INT; EXEC @return_value = MyProcedure; SELECT @return_value")`